# How does IDA understand that the file was packed by packer?

Tags: ida, packers

So, how does IDA understand that the file was packed by a packer?

How does it distinguishes between different types of packers?

Are they leave some significant signatures or some patterns of byte code?

Or maybe they do modify the header of the file in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA don't detect type of packer. Also, signatures are not used. Instead, it analyze PE-header: .idata section, entry point and import entries.
This method is very accurate, has low false positives.